# FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage redirecting to default.aspx

Tags: asp.net

I'm using forms authentication to authenticate a user and then redirect the user to
    welcome page, which is Welcome.aspx. When the user credentials are valid, then the user 
    will be redirected to Welcome.aspx page.

I am using
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() method to redirect the user to the welcome
   page, but for some reason the FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() method is
   redirecting the user to Default.aspx.

**Web.Config Code:**

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"  defaultUrl="~/Welcome.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are only allowing authorized user to acccess the pages by specifying `<deny users="?" />`

Add this to your web.config file for welcome.aspx redirect.

```
<location path="Welcome.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: now that's going to allow everyone to navigate and view web pages in the directory  because you are allowing everyone access to the pages in the directory.i want the users to be able to view other pages only after sucessfull login,that's why i have marked deny access to anonymous users <deny users="?">

Comment: No, We are only allowing Welcome.aspx page for anonymous user, check the location tag on top. For more info on location tag, go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> The DefaultUrl property is used by the RedirectFromLoginPage method if
>   no return URL is included in the request.

so you may have `Default.aspx` as return URL, or you may have set `Default.aspx` as defaultDocument

Comment: but then i have already specified the default url in the defaulturl property under the authenticaiton element <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Welcome.aspx"/> in the web.config file which should redirect the user to the page specified in the defaulturl property after sucessfull login.but then why is it redirecting me back to default.aspx page and not UserMainPage.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to redirect the user to the page they were *just viewing.* That's why it goes back to `default.aspx`. You just need to issue a redirect to the actual welcome page--statically.